# Best way to create public functions in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp

I need create, 1 or more files, to concentrate all functions about a specific operation, for example:

- Return a sum of a customer check.
- Close a check of specific customer.
- Transfer all items of specific table to other.

But the functions use 2 or more Models, and perform some operations in database (crud).

I need create a Behavior or Component?

How can I use 1 or more models in Behavior/Component? **Reference**? **ClassRegistry**? **loadModel**()?

What the best pratice?

---

*If some user can edit my text, to be more clear for others, I appreciate that. And, If Title isn't correct, change too. Thank you.*
*Sorry about my english. It's bad I know*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ticket lacks a huge amount of information but let me try to guess it:

This sounds like you have three or four models and their data should be related to each other. I assume it is something like:

Tables:

- Customer
- Check
- CartsItem
- BoughtItem

Assocs:

- Customer hasMany Check
- Customer hasMany CartsItem
- BoughtItem belongs to Customer

What you call your "lib" and you want to trigger is for sure triggered just by a single action, something like a "checkout" or "run report" action. To me it sounds like you want to checkout a cart or generate an item list for a customer.

Inside your Customer model have a method like that:

```
public function report($customerId, $checkid) {
    $sum = $this->Check->calculateSum($customerId, $checkId);
    $checkClosed = $this->Check->close($checkId);
    $items = $this->CartsItem->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('CartsItem.customer_id' => $customerId)));
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $this->BoughtItem->save($item['CartsItem']);
    }
    $this->CartsItem->deleteAll(array('CartsItem.customer_id' => $customerId));
    return compact('sum', 'checkClosed', 'items');
}
```

If your data is not related use ClassRegistry::init('ModelName'); to get instances of another model.

But the key point is all of what you do is data manipulation so it is a clear job for a model method. If you need params from the request simply pass them as argument to that method. Your method can return whatever you need, it's up to you.

A "lib" is *not* the right place or even pattern for what you want to do.

Comment: I also would not use libs for this. I have been using cake for about 5 years and have never needed to use libs. This answer makes more sense.

Comment: @burzum Yes, you correctly. I'm currently using an action inside the same controller, and using only existing relations, and when not, loadModel (). Anyway, thanks.